# Why the Cog is not loading?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I created a discord bot with cog and extensions, but the commands aren't being imported

Main file:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
intents.members = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=commands.when_mentioned_or('!'), intents=intents)
bot.remove_command('help')

            
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Bot ready as {bot.user}')  


bot.load_extension('.ext.moderation')
    
bot.run(***)
```

"Moderation.py" extension:

```py
import discord
import datetime
from discord.ext import commands
from ..functions import Time


class Moderation(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        
    @commands.command()
    @commands.has_permissions(ban_members = True)
    async def ban(self, ctx, member : discord.Member = None, *, reason = None):
        if member == None:
            await ctx.send('Você deve especificar um membro para ser banido!', delete_after = 10)
        else:
            await member.ban(reason = reason)
                
    @commands.command()
    @commands.has_permissions(kick_members = True)
    async def kick(self, ctx, member : discord.Member = None, *, reason = None):
        if member == None:
            await ctx.send('Você deve especificar um membro para ser expulso!', delete_after = 10)
        else:
            await member.kick(reason = reason)
        
    @commands.command()
    @commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
    async def unban(self, ctx, *, member = None):
        if member == None:
            await ctx.send('Você deve especificar um membro para ser desbanido!', delete_after = 10)
        else:
            banned_users = await ctx.guild.bans()
            member_name, member_discriminator = member.split("#")

            for ban_entry in banned_users:
                user = ban_entry.user

                if (user.name, user.discriminator) == (member_name, member_discriminator):
                    await ctx.guild.unban(user)
                    await ctx.send(f'Unbanned {user.mention}')
                    return
            else:
                await ctx.send('O membro não está banido!')
            
    @commands.command(aliases=['purge','clean','limpar'])
    @commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
    async def clear(self, ctx, amount: int = 10):
        try:
            int(amount)
        except: 
            await ctx.send('Insira um número válido.', delete_after=5)
        else:
            await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
            await ctx.send(f'Apagou {amount} mensagens.', delete_after=5)
            
    @commands.command(aliases=['mute'])
    @commands.has_role('Mod' or 'Admin')
    async def timeout(self, ctx, member : discord.Member, duration = '30m', *, reason = None):
        lenght = Time.input_convert(duration)
        if lenght == -1:
            await ctx.send('Duração inválida! Digite a duração no formato (s/m/d/h).')
        else:
            lenght = datetime.timedelta(seconds = lenght)
            await member.timeout(until = lenght, reason = reason)


def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Moderation(bot))
```

But whenever I try to use a command, this appears in the console instead: `discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "ban" is not found`

Where is the error?

I tried to change some parts of the code, using just Cogs or just extensions, but it isn't working anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the latest version of discord.py, loading Cogs is Asynchronous now!

Do this for your main file:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
intents.members = True

class BotClient(commands.Bot):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(command_prefix=commands.when_mentioned_or('!'), intents=intents, help_command=None)

    async def setup_hook(self):
        await self.load_extension('ext.moderation')
        # Load cogs here

    async def on_ready(self):
        print(f'Bot ready as {self.user}')

bot = BotClient()
bot.run(***)
```

Then change the setup function on the cog with this:

```
async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(Moderation(bot))'
```

More on this change:
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html#extension-and-cog-loading-unloading-is-now-asynchronous

Migrating to v2.0: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html#